# Does shimosh.com violate "attribution required"?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, copyright, creative-commons

I was [googling about Perl 6 regex](https://www.google.com/search?q=quantifier+quantifies+nothing), realising I previously [asked a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024489/quantifier-quantifies-nothing-but-i-never-asked-for-a-quantifier), and in the google results, with the same page title I found:

[image: smoooosh]

```
http://www.simosh.com/article/dfaceeij-quantifier-quantifies-nothing-but-i-never-asked-for-a-quantifier.html
```

The page serves ads (some that AdBlock doesn't block!!!1!), and I see my username and profile picture, and the username and profile picture of the accepted answer, but there are no links to Stack Overflow or the question itself, and neither my profile page nor Christoph's. The `related posts` section has links but they go to e.g

```
http://www.simosh.com/article/dhbdcja-javascript-invalid-quantifier-in-regex.html`
```

They also have a pretty nice racket on the rest of SO: `http://www.simosh.com/`

There's nothing on those pages that allow me to get here from there; indeed they even say `© 2016 Powered by Simosh.com`. I'm not really sure the © has any meaning nor what it's referring to but fair enough.

Lastly, there are some links at the bottom of the page that trigger JavaScript `alert();`s. All of them are complete gibberish (mushy inspirational quotes, anyone?) except for the one titled `Privacy statement`:

> Some of the informations on this site are from interent and all rights belong to their respective owners. If you think your copyright has been infringed, please contact us and we will remove them.~

[sic]

Is this a violation of Creative Commons / SE's license? If it is, I'll report it to SE, but I'd like to know here first if I am incorrect.

Comment: @Meta Really? That was simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The license states "You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor".

I'm not a lawyer, but I think the "licensor" is stack overflow, and they specify four attribution requirements:

> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn't have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

(see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Your name is attached to the question, so they are complying with the third point. But none of the others.

I think instead of asking them to take it down, you should encourage them to comply with the license properly.

Comment: I reported them to SE. I could email them myself, but at the end of the day, it's SE's license and job to enforce it, and they'll do a way better job of this anyways. :)